# refresh button in databricks which when clicked runs specified cells

Tags: azure-databricks

Is their any refresh button widget I can use in databricks, when clicked runs only specified cells.
and is their any way to run specified databricks cells when all the required combobox and text box values are selected in databricks?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any refresh button widget I can use in databricks?

There is no widget like button in databricks. there are only 4 widgets **text**, **dropdown**, **combobox**, **multiselect**.

> is their any way to run specified databricks cells when all the required combobox and text box values are selected in databricks?

There is option **Run Accessed Commands** in widget’s execution behavior. Whenever you enter or select new value, Only the cells that retrieve the values for that particular widget are rerun.

[image]

***Output only running Cmd5 cell***

Here I am Accessing Widget values in Cmd5 cell with `dbutils.widget.get` command because of this widget’s execution behavior is only executing Cmd5 cell.

[image]